# HTTP POST to a backbase application

Tags: http-post, backbase-portal

I need to implement a requirement in which other non-backbase applications will send a HTTP POST request to my bb application. There is some pre processing & validation which is to be done and then based on the result the client has to be redirected to the login page or an error page.

What is the best way to implement this in backbase?

Comment: "based on the result the client has to be ..." : Who is the client here -> the non-backbase application or backbase client?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the documentation about **Integration Services**. 
The full documentation about you can find here: https://my.backbase.com/docs/product-documentation/documentation//portal/5.6.2/develop_integrationservices.html

The documentation will help you to develop own service (I prefer use Camel Java DSL way), and you will get the url like:

`http://localhost:7777/portalserver/services/rest/v1/myService`.

here the example of Java implementation of service:

```
public class MyCamelService extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("restlet:/v1/myService")
          .setBody().constant("<html><body><b>Hello World!</b></body></html>")
          .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("text/html"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some resource or material where I can learn how to integrate Backbase with third party microservices from scratch? In my case I do not have access to Backbase server as it is hosted by another vendor. I only need to focus on managing my middle tier. Simple demo app in Spring microservice would be a great help.